# multiple pie chart for each row pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, charts

I would like to create multiple pie chart for each continent to show the alcohol serving with percentage on it.[image: dataframe]

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.plot.pie`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html) with transpose dataframe by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'beer':[1,2,3],
                   'spirit':[4,5,6],
                   'wine':[7,8,9]}, index=['Africa','Asia','Europe'])

print (df)
        beer  spirit  wine
Africa     1       4     7
Asia       2       5     8
Europe     3       6     9

df.T.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(10, 3))
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2):

here is the code, I found this kind more flexible

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd   

df = pd.DataFrame({'beer':[1,2,3],
               'spirit':[4,5,6],
               'wine':[7,8,9]}, index=['Africa','Asia','Europe'])    

df= df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=df.index.size, ncols=1, figsize=(7,7))

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.05)

for row in range(df.index.size + 1):
    fig.add_subplot(axs[row] )
    plt.pie(df.loc[df.index[row],:], labels=df.columns)
    plt.axis('off')
```